# Net Core and JQuery autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-core, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Im having some real problems getting JQuery autocomplete to work in Net Core.

here is my client side script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#txtSystemUserDisplayName').autocomplete({
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $('#txtSystemUserDisplayName').val("");
            }
        },

        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "@(Url.Action("SearchEmployeesAJAX", "Home" ))",
               // data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term.replace(/'/gi, "\\'") + "'}",
                data: { term: 'fumanchu' },
                dataType: "json", type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);
                    response($.map(x, function (item) {

                        return {
                            label: item.employeeDisplayName,
                           
                        }
                    }))



                }, error: function (response) { alert(response.responseText); }, failure: function (response) { alert(response.responseText); }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {


            $("#hfSystemUserDisplayName").val(i.item.label);





        },
        minLength: 1
    });

});
```

Now when i start typing , the autocomplete fires but the param in the controller method is NULL , no matter what i do. it doesnt matter what i call the 'term' in the data object of the request. And yes i am making sure that the controller method parameter is named the same . eg

```
public JsonResult SearchEmployeesAJAX(String term) {
```

as you can see ive even commented it out and hardcoded a string in there, still null.
it DOES work if I set the string as part of the URL eg:

```
url: "@(Url.Action("SearchEmployeesAJAX", "Home", new {@term="blahblahblah" }
```

This is how I have always done autocompletes in the past on .Net Framework, and never had an issue. Is there something different about Net Core that im not aware of, maybe something different about how requests are formed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's more likely to be something wrong when you send the ajax request and make your controller failed to receive the parameters. Anyway you've solved your issue, congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anyone else is also having this problem, it appears that you cant use the Url.Action helper anymore and still have the parameter not be null.
You will need to use a raw string as the url instead, which seemed to solve this.